# eval lines from a file

Tags: python, file, eval

I am creating a program that stores options in a txt file, and I tried a few different lines but so far I think an `eval` is the best one.

I got this info in the file:

```
colordefondo = "#abcdef"
```

and I got this `eval` in the program:

```
for line in open("filename.txt", "r"):
  eval(line)
```

However, when I try the code it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\project-sae\Sae.py", line 25, in <module>
eval(line)
File "<string>", line 1
colordefondo = "#abcdef"
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

My question is Why? And if anyone knows a better way to load and store the value of several options from a txt file it would be great. Nevertheless my question is about why that `eval` is failing, my knowledge about how `eval` works seems wrong and I don't know why, used it several times before, just never from a file.

Comment: Have you considered using [ConfigParser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html)? Sounds like that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: exactly, i was trying to mimic an INI file with python. I didn't know ConfigParser exists, thanks :D

Comment: @Saelyth: Unless your problem is actually to write something that executes Python code (like, say, a replacement for IDLE), `eval` and `exec` are almost _never_ the answer. They're just a way to add a new set of problems without solving what you were trying to solve.

Comment: yeah i think i'll just try the ConfigParser, seems more appropiated for this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation says, ['eval'](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) evaluates an *expression*. Not a statement. Assignments are statements.

You could use the `exec` statement. But if you want to exec all of the lines of a file, that's exactly what [`execfile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#execfile) does. (I'm assuming Python 2.x here; things are a little different in 3.x, but the idea is similar.)

However, this is a bad idea to do in the first place. A better way to load and store the value of several options from a txt file is to use *anything other than Python source* as your format. JSON, .ini files, .rc files, etc. Python comes with code built-in to handle a variety of such formats. See [File Formats](http://docs.python.org/2/library/fileformats.html) and [Internet Data Handling](http://docs.python.org/2/library/netdata.html) for a list of the relevant modules, read through them, and pick the one you want.

Comment: _"A better way to load and store the value of several options from a txt file is to use anything other than Python source as your format."_ Why? If what you're trying to do is quickly provide a swappable set of values for a program to use, why do you need to go through the trouble of designing and parsing a format? This is pretty much the same thing as an `import` does, and we don't fret about that. Also, in Python 3.0, `execfile()` has been removed, now `exec(open(fn).read())` is the official way.